# PWA install button click tracking

Tags: progressive-web-apps

PWA install icon

[image: 1]

Dear All,

I would like to understand that how to track in Adobe analytics the PWA install button.

Need to track "How many visitor click on install button (below screenshot)".

Please guide. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure about the Adobe Analytics part but you can use the `appinstalled` event

Comment: Thank you for the information Grimsteel (https://stackoverflow.com/users/21401123/grimsteel)